# I'm getting Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isSMTP() on null Error on my Submission of the Form in PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm getting Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isSMTP() on null error in my PHP mailer code. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```php
<?php

 if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    require 'Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer.php';
    require 'SMTP.php';

    $mail->isSMTP();

    $mail->Host = 'mail.nsacedu.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = '';
    $mail->Password = '';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 465;  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of the PHPMailer class. The require just give you the class itself :)

```
$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
```